# Is there a way to select 2 different time ranges in a prometheus time series and show them at the same panel in grafana?

Tags: time-series, prometheus, grafana, victoriametrics

Let's say i have a prometheus time series showing the power consumption from my power panel. I want to get the average consumption from 02:00 to 08:00 and from 15:00 to 17:00 on the same day and show them on the same panel in grafana. Assume that i have a time series of the above data starting from 00:00 and ending at 23:59 on the same day with a data point each second. I have tried playing with relative times, intervals and offsets but it is so frustrating i have been confused. Victoria metrics is also supported as i am using it to store the data series. I am thinking on changing to influxdb because it seems clearer to me how to do that with the language it supports but i would like to stay to just prometheus and victoriametrics.

i tried getting the first time range from 02:00 to 08:00 by using offsets and time intervals grafana offers but i failed. Even if it worked, i then would not have any clue how to do that with the other time range from 15:00-17:00.

Comment: Can you explain in more details? You want to show graph 02-08 and then immediately after it 15-17? Or do you want to see them in parallel?

Comment: Also, why not simply use to neighboring panels with different time-shift/relative-time configs?

Comment: Yes, sorry it is my first time asking a question. I want to take an average of each one of the time ranges and sum them up into one value. Something like sum(avg(time_series[02:00-08:00]) + avg(time_series[15:00-17:00]))

Comment: Do you expect your panel to show a single value? What it supposed to show at 04:00: avg 02-04, or 04-08 yesterday + 15-17 yesterday + 02-04 today? Also, what does avg(something) + avg(something_else) supposed to represent? It that an attempt to calculate average over all?

Comment: I want the panel to show one single value. The sum of two averages. The one average over time will be from 02:00 to 00:08 and the other from 15:00 to 17:00. Those time ranges represent the night energy price from the energy provider so i want to calculate the total average energy consumed at these time intervals.  At 04:00 i want the panel to show avg 02:00-04:00, because the calculation has meaning for each individual day only. In conclusion i want for each different day to show the total energy consumed at night energy price time ranges and the day (which will be easy when i find the night).

Comment: Try `sum_over_time( (node_cpu_seconds_totaland on() ((hour() >= 2<=5)and floor(vector(time())/86400)== on()floor( topk(1,timestamp( up@end() ))/86400) ) ) [24h:]) + <the same but with other limit near hour()>`

Comment: Can you please break down the query and explain its parts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get average value of metric `my_metric` over window of time between 02:00 and 08:00 of current date, with preserving result till the midnight, you can use following query:

```
avg_over_time(
 (my_metric
  and on() (
    (hour() >= 2<8) 
    and
    floor(vector(time())/86400) == on() floor(topk(1,timestamp(up@end()))/86400)
  )
 ) 
[24h:])
```

What's happening here:

- `avg_over_time` calculates average over specified range vector. In this case we need simple average, as all the filtration will happen inside range selector.
- `my_metric and on()` taking metric and filtering it base on following expressions ignoring all the labels.

  - `hour() >= 2<8)` first filtering expression: function `hour()` should return value between greater or equal than 2 and less than 8,
  - `and` second expression must be true an the same time as first one. No need for `on()` since both of expressions don't have any labels.
  - `floor(vector(time())/86400) == on() floor(topk(1,timestamp(up@end()))/86400)` second filtering expression, to take only those values of metric that are within day that correspond to end of query time range. A bit more explanation:

    - `floor(vector(time())/86400)` simply calculates whole division part of timestamp by 86400. This is to find 00:00:00 of day to which value belongs.
    - `floor(topk(1,timestamp(up@end()))/86400)` does similar to previous one, but it calculates 00:00:00 of the day, to which belong the end of time range selected (end of range selected for dashboard in Grafana in your case). Here `up@end()` simply returns value of metric `up` on the range end, then `timestamp` extracts it's timestamp. `topk(1, .. )` is used to get only one value of results (metric `up` has multiples, use of `up` is arbitrary and whole construct can be replaced with some metric that is guarantied to have a singe value at any time).

---

Total query according to what you described in question will look like this (even though I still believe that there is no sence what so ever in addition of two averages):

```
avg_over_time(
 (my_metric
  and on() (
    (hour() >= 2<8) 
    and
    floor(vector(time())/86400) == on() floor(topk(1,timestamp(up@end()))/86400)
  )
 ) 
[24h:])
+
avg_over_time(
 (my_metric
  and on() (
    (hour() >= 15<17) 
    and
    floor(vector(time())/86400) == on() floor(topk(1,timestamp(up@end()))/86400)
  )
 ) 
[24h:])
```

Comment: you are right, summing up two averages was nonsense, i won't be doing that. Nevertheless you helped me a lot, that was what i was looking for! Thanks